# Check whether rad tree view node from same parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik treeView in my ASP.NET web application.I want to check whether checked node from same parent of previous node parent or not on some condition client side. How it possible?

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but have a look at the client-side API the nodes offer: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-basics.html. you can get their parent node and compare it against the parent node of the other node you have. Examine the other articles too, like this one: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreenode.html and this one http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreenodecollection.html.